# Unable to update objects and initialize form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a Project model as follows:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    launch_date = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    possession_date = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
```

Each project has a set of permissions which are in the permission table:

```
class Permissions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now there may be multiple permissions in the permission table. For each permission in the permission table, there is a corresponding value such as granted/applied etc. So there is a project permission table as follows:

```
class ProjectPermission(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
    permission = models.ForeignKey('Permissions')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So i made the form as follows :

```
class PermissionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PermissionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        permissions = Permissions.objects.all()
        for permission in permissions:
            self.fields[permission.name] = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.Select(choices=(
                    ('Approved', 'Approved'),
                    ('In Process', 'In Process'),
                    ('Not Applied', 'Not Applied'),
                    ('Denied', 'Denied'),
                )))

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.disable_csrf = True
        self.helper.form_id = 'permission-form'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        project = kwargs.pop('project')
        for field in self.fields:
            permission = Permissions.objects.filter(name=field).first()
            p = ProjectPermission(
                project=project,
                permission=permission,
                value=self.cleaned_data[field]
            )
            p.save()
        return project
```

But the problem is that one the data is saved, I am unable to re-render the form with the correct data and nor am I able to update the data. If I change the value of a field and save the form, it creates a new entry in the ProjectPermission table.

Is this because I haven't specified an instance while initializing the form? If so how can I specify the instance ?

Comment: You may want to look at [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) to save you some effort here.

Answer (score 0):

Django has [`ModelForms` to save you repeating your model code in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform). I assume you're using [crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) from the code you've posted. I'll take you through a simple ModelForms example.

First I like to create a base form class of my own to factor out some common layout, like so:

```
# core Django imports
from django.forms import ModelForm

# third-party imports
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper


class MyForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
```

Now lets say we have a model like this that we want to create/update/ and so on:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    """
    Represents an individual event.

    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    date = models.DateField(help_text='dd/mm/yyyy')
    start_time = models.TimeField(help_text='HH:MM - 24hr clock')
    finish_time = models.TimeField(help_text='HH:MM - 24hr clock')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    attendees_need_to_sign_up = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text="Tick the box if you're giving an open invite to attend",
    )
    organiser = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        related_name = "organiser",
    )
    ...
```

You can now have a ModelForm like this:

```
class EventForm(MyForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper.form_id = 'event-form'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field(
                'topic',
                template='events/related_topic.html',
            ),
            Field('name', css_class='input-xlarge'),
            Field('agenda', css_class='input-xlarge'),
            Field('date', css_class='input-xlarge'),
            Field('start_time', css_class='input-xlarge'),
            Field('finish_time', css_class='input-xlarge'),
            Field('location', css_class = 'input-xlarge'),
            Field('attendees_need_to_sign_up', css_class = 'input-xlarge'),
            FormActions(
                Submit(
                    'save_changes',
                    'Save changes',
                    css_class = "btn-primary",
                ),
                Button(
                    'cancel',
                    'Cancel',
                    onclick = 'history.go(-1);'
                ),
            ),
        )
        self.fields['name'].label = 'Event name'

    def clean(self):
        # custom validation goes here
        ...

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = (
            'topic',
            'name',
            'agenda',
            'date',
            'start_time',
            'finish_time',
            'location',
            'attendees_need_to_sign_up',
        )
```

And now you just need your views and templates. Views are as easy as:

```
# core django imports
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import (
    CreateView,
    DetailView,
    ListView,
    UpdateView,
)

# third party imports
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin
...

class EventCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventForm
    login_url = "/login/"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['topics'] = Topic.objects.all()
        return context


class EventUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventUpdateForm
    login_url = "/login/"
```

The LoginRequiredMixin there is coming from [Django braces](https://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Your template is now very simple because you've defined all the form in your Python code. You need to include crispy forms template tags by placing the following right after the `{% extends %}` declaration:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
```

And then just place:

```
{% crispy form %}
```

wherever you want the form.

Comment: I know the use of model forms. They tend to create/update a row in the database. This isn't my case.